# High iowait causing problems

Tags: iowait

Since a week I've been suffering from a server with VPS servers that is very slow and has a lot of IOWAIT. Can someone explain or tell what is causing this problems?

Command: `iotop -aoP`

```
  PID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
 338273 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 % 33.41 % [kworker/u130:0-events_unbound]
 344858 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  6.02 % [kworker/u129:2-events_unbound]
   1053 be/3 root          0.00 B    652.00 K  0.00 %  6.02 % [jbd2/sda5-8]
 339496 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  5.77 % [kworker/u129:1-events_unbound]
 326781 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  3.15 % [kworker/u129:3-events_power_efficient]
```

Answer (score 0):

Speak to your service provider.

Read and write requests are backing up on your server. Your workload is exceeding the available capacity. This is all to do with the hardware - which you have no control over, you don't even have visibility of.

Comment: The server is hosted by myself, I once enabled external backup for VPSes. However, I suspected that this would cause problems, so I turned it off. But I understand that it keeps going?

Comment: Then it's not a VPS. It's a VM. Problem remains the same, the VM is trying to use too much of the avilable capacility. You'd need to look at the hypervisor and the other VMs running to determine if thats because of what is happening inside this VM or stuff happenning elsewhere is reducing the capacity available for this host.

Comment: Hi, it does not look like the VMS are causing the high iowait. How can I see what VM is using to much?

Comment: And its a server thats running VM (VPS) servers.

Comment: No it's not. Your terminology is very confused. Its really hard to help you solve a problem you can't describe. Suggest you shut this down and open a new post describing what the setup actually is and what metrics you see on all the hosts.